# I am getting this error ?? can anyone advise why I can not see why

Tags: mysql

SQL query:

```
"INSERT INTO `ORDER_HEADER` (`order_ID`, `customer_ID`, `time_of_sale`, `net_total`) 
VALUES (NULL, {$_SESSION['customer_ID']}, NOW(), '{$_SESSION['grand_total']}')"
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"INSERT INTO `ORDER_HEADER` (`order_ID`, `customer_ID`, `time_of_sale`, `net_tot' at line 1

Comment: Look at the generated SQL, not the PHP that generates it. (Not that you should be building SQL by mashing strings together anyway, use prepared statements).

Comment: Why are you wrapping your values in `{}`?

Comment: Please, please, please read about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra quote at the beginning,from your error.You have to look just before mysql tells you about the error in your query.

```
'"INSERT
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey bro you forgot to enclose this value within single quotes
(') `{$_SESSION['customer_ID']}`

Hence you r getting syntax error

Happy Coding :)

Comment: `{}` flower braces wont be parsed in that case

Answer (score 0):

According to your error you seem to have an extra quote in the beginning. You could also be having an issue with the string concatenation of your $_SESSION variables.

Have you tried using php PDO statements? The will make your life MUCH easier, and they can be used to prevent SQL injection attacks and generally just make your code more secure.

Here's my favorite tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

And the docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php